# neo4j - autocomplete javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, neo4j

My web application starts with a form that takes a list of comma-separated usernames and then queries the neo4j database for each one.

I want to add autocomplete functionality when typing the usernames, so that users can type a person's full name (a property of each node in the database) and have it autocomplete with suggestions in a facebook-style.

Can neo4j support this? What would be the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

Try http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, and on the function, do a search

```
start n = node:person_index('name:sta*') return n
```

where `sta` is the beginning of your current typing on the UI.

Comment: I'm using the Java API for the rest of the program, so I was thinking of using nodeIndex.query("property", "*name*"); but unsure if there would be a large performance difference?

Comment: I can't find the right documentation that talks about this particular use of the <something>_index, can you point me to it?